# Search literal within a word

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a way to perform a FULLTEXT search which returns literals found **within** words?

I have been using `MATCH(col) AGAINST('+literal*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` but it fails if the text is like:

- `blah,blah,literal,blah`
- `blahliteralblah`
- `blah,blah,literal`

Please Note that there is no space after commas.

I want all three cases above to be returned.

Comment: you can always do like '%literal%' if performance is not an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that should be better fetching the array of entries and then perform a text manipulation over the fetched data (in this case a search)!

Because any text manipulation or complex query take more resources and if your database contains a lot of data, the query become too slow! Moreover, if you are running your 
query on a shared server, that increases the performance issues!

You can easily accomplish what you are trying to do with regex, once you have fetched the data from the database!

---

**UPDATE:** My suggestion is the same even if you are running your script on a dedicated server! However, if you want to perform a full-text search of the word "literal" in BOOLEAN MODE like you have described, you can remove the `+` operator (because you are searching only one word) and construct the query as follow:

```
SELECT listOfColumsNames WHERE
MATCH (colName) 
AGAINST ('literal*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However, even if you add the AND operator, your query works fine: tested on Apache Server with MySQL 5.1!

I suggest you to read [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) about the full-text search in boolean mode.

The only one problem of this query is that doesn't matches the word "literal" if it is a sub-string inside an other word, for example: "textliteraltext".
As you noticed, you can't use the `*` operator at the beginning of the word!

So, to accomplish what you are trying to do, the fastest and easiest way is to follow the suggestion of Paul, using the `%` placeholder:

```
SELECT listOfColumsNames 
WHERE colName LIKE '%literal%';
```

Comment: +1. Apache Lucene(Java), Zend Lucene(PHP), DotLucene(.Net) all are stable, powerful and popular.

Comment: But is there no way of doing this with MATCH .. AGAINST? I am working on a code with a single client and a dedicated server - the only constraint is that the client should get the data as quickly as possible.

I mean if the * wildcard works for characters following a searched literal, why is there no fast implementation for characters preceding a searched literal?